# debugging webgl in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl, google-chrome-devtools

I have a webgl page running in chrome.

Every now and then chrome will report the following error.

[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to render with no buffer attached to enabled attribute 1

I've tried to debug where the error is occurring but I cannot. I can reliably cause it to occur, but when I debug the error is reported on seemingly random lines. I suspect this is because of the asynchronous nature of gpu rendering.

Is there a good way to debug this?

Comment: try to use the `gl.vertexAttrib4f(...)` instead of `gl.vertexAttrib1f(...)`. I get a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584589/why-i-cant-use-uniform1f-instead-of-uniform4f-for-the-gl-fragcolor-initializing (nobody answered still).

Comment: @Bush vertexAttrib4f is setting all values of a *disabled* Vertex Attribute Array, used as a *default value* and not at all needed if you plan to actually supply those values from a buffer. It has no effect once you enable it.

Comment: @ScreeniusBlack I know and I expected the same for the `uniform1f` (for the `uniform` variable), but I got the problem. Look my link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [debug wrapper](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Debugging#Programmatically_Debugging_WebGL_applications) to wrap the WebGL context and call gl.getError after every WebGL function.

There is [an example of one](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Debugging#Programmatically_Debugging_WebGL_applications) available on [the official WebGL Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/).

Comment: I actually ended up using this. It looks like when I wrap the GL context with this debug code it will report the error on the same line each time. Pretty handy. now I just need to figure out why it is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Per default WebGL doesn't tell you much about it, you have to query all the information you need yourself. Once you know how to do that, those errors will tell you all you need to debug it. The getter for your case would be

```
var attribLocation = 1;
gl.getVertexAttrib ( attribLocation, gl.VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING );
```

Which, if you query it before your draw call, will probably return `null`, which means you're not calling `vertexAttribPointer` correctly when setting up or switching buffers.

So you go to the point in your code where you set the pointers and enable the arrays and confirm that the location you just enabled with `enableVertexAttribArray` returns also returns `null` if you query the buffer at this point. Now you know if you messed up with the pointer. You know you fixed it, when the query returns the correct `WebGLBuffer` Object.

There are getters for all the states (WebGL is mostly about managing state), they are a bit tricky to use, but using them will greatly help you understand everything going on all the time, when you need or don't need to make calls in order to update that state and where you made mistakes.

You can look the getters and the arguments they take up [in the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/)

Answer (score 1):

SpectorJS is a tool aimed at WebGl developers wanting to know what happens in their context. It enables capturing of all the available information from a frame. You will be able to look at your entire commands list with their associated visual states and context information.

https://github.com/BabylonJS/Spector.js